# Basic Differential Calculus

Tags: calculus

In an earlier question i asked for explanations of concepts that were boggling my mind with respect to the following question, but I'm still not making any headway. Please I need help.

Given $\vec A = x^2\hat x - \hat y + xz\hat z$ and $\vec B= y\hat x + x\hat y - xyz\hat z$, evaluate $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y} [ \vec A \times \vec B]$, at the point $(1, -1, 2)$.

Comment: Please have a look at the exits I have made to your question, and see if they're correct.  If you click the 'edit' button, you can see the MathJax source I used (which uses $\LaTeX$-like syntax and is how mathematics is formatted on this site); maybe you can work it out for yourself and see how to make any changes you need to make on your own.

Comment: Maybe you should include a link to the earlier question so we can better see where you need help.

Answer (score 2):

In coordinates
$$
\vec{A}=(x^2,-1,xz)
$$
and
$$
\vec{B}=(y,x,-xyz).
$$
Use the definition of $\vec{A}\times\vec{B}$ to compute it and then take the appropriate partial derivatives.

Comment: Could you help me solve it? :-)